# The sum of independent discrete Gaussians is a discrete Gaussian

Tags: lattice-crypto, gaussian-noise

I am currently learning about lattice-based cryptography and, reading from [A Decade of Lattice Cryptography](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/939.pdf) by Peikert, specifically section 2.3, it emerges that

*[...] if the parameter s is greater or equal than the smoothing parameter of a lattice, then the sum of independent discrete gaussians (over that lattice) is a discrete gaussian itself.*

I am looking for the formal statement (and proof) of that fact without any success. Is anyone able to point me to the appropriate reference?

EDIT: added link to the paper

Comment: The sentence immediately preceding the claim in the same paragraph lists a bunch of references: "Several works, e.g., ... have shown ..."

Comment: @Myath Unfortunately each reference is very dense and carries a lot of highly non-trivial results. I'm sure that an exhaustive answer is to be found in one or more of the references, but from a first scan of them I did not find a clear statement of the result. I was just wondering if anyone more experienced could help narrowing down the research

Comment: This statement (in a more general form) was first proved in https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/pargauss.pdf .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention

> Unfortunately each reference is very dense and carries a lot of highly non-trivial results. I'm sure that an exhaustive answer is to be found in one or more of the references, but from a first scan of them I did not find a clear statement of the result.

This can be found in Theorem 4.6 of [Improved Discrete Gaussian and Subgaussian Analysis
for Lattice Cryptography](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/337.pdf).